# Python regex save data

Tags: python, regex

I am searching for a string using regex.  My regex works, but how do I combine the two.  I was not sure if I would be able to just save the regex from re.sub.  Is that possible? Or do I have to have them separate.  I want to save the line findme=18d78haf in a variable and remove the line from the string f1. Is this possible using less code?

```
f1.read()
a = re.compile(r'findme=(.?)*') 
a = a.search(f1).group(0) 
f1 = re.sub(r'findme=(.?)*', '', f1)
```

Comment: can you be more specific? you'd better write down original string and your expected outcome.

Comment: This syntax `(.?)*` is discouraged. The better one is this `.*`. You can (and probably should) use it to store the match. Then use it again to replace (_all_?), if you only have 1 item to save, and there is only 1 item, _and_ if python supports a callback, you can do both at the same time - save group 0 to the variable in the callback, and return `''` to replace it with nothing.

Comment: The read me file contains the following after reading it.
readme ="""
blah blah stuff is in here
findme=123sdfasdf
more information here 
"""

    with open(readme) as f:
        f1 = f.read()
        a = re.compile(r'findme=(.?)*')
        a = a.search(f1).group(0)  #Saves findme=whateverwehave from    f1 string. To variable a
    f1 = re.sub(r'findme=(.?)*', '', f1) #removes findme=whateverwehave from the f1 string.
    
What I want is instead of compiling and finding the string and saving the findme=whatever123 to variable a. 
Is there a way to just do all of it in one line.

Comment: Like I said, python should have a regex _callback_ feature. You can store _group 0_ in a global variable, inside it, then return `""` to replace it. Google if python has the regex callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-use regular expressions by pre-compiling them. see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile).

```
import re
f1="test string"
regexpattern= re.compile(r'findme=(.?)*')
regexpattern.sub(f1, '')
regexpattern.search(f1)
```